# Kubernetes use {{ include xx }} inside values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm refactoring a helm chart, and wanted to put some values from `deployment.yaml` to `values.yaml` and that value is

```
hosts:
  - {{ include "myApp.externalHostName" . | quote }}
```

but it gives me the error

```
[ERROR] values.yaml: unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to
 JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"toJson
 include \"myApp.externalHostName\" . | quote":interface {}(nil)}

[ERROR] templates/: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to
 JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"toJson
 include \"myApp.externalHostName\" . | quote":interface {}(nil)}
```

it would work if I just used

```
hosts:
  - myExternalHostname.something
```

but is it possible to run include in values.yaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `values.yaml` files are not subject to golang interpolation. If you need dynamic content, you'll need to update files inside the `templates` directory (which are subject to golang interpolation), or generate the `values.yaml` content using another mechanism

In this specific case, you may find yaml anchors to be helpful:

```yaml
myApp:
  externalHostName: &externalHostName myapp.example.com

theIngressOrWhatever:
  hosts:
  - *externalHostName
```

Comment: well too bad if I cant use golang interpolation, but that's life, and thanks for suggestion with anchors